# Could not find com.appdynamics:appdynamics-gradle-plugin:2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

UPDATED Q : I have tried to run this sample eCommerce app on android studio 1.2.1, build 141.1903![enter image description here][1]..

https://github.com/Appdynamics/ECommerce-Android

and i did what is instructed to run it
but it keeps asking to upgrade gradle to gradle 2.0 or advance.(after i downloaded the new version 2.4).

how to upgrade or integrate gradle in android studio?
what other problems related to it I have to solve?

error I'm getting

Error:

1. Could not find com.appdynamics:appdynamics-gradle-plugin:2.0.

   Searched in the following locations:
       file //ANDRO1/gradle/m2repository/com/appdynamics/appdynamics-gradle-plugin/2.0/appdynamics-gradle-plugin-2.0.pom

file://ANDRO1/gradle/m2repository/com/appdynamics/appdynamics-gradle-plugin/2.0/appdynamics-gradle-plugin-2.0.jar

https // repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/appdynamics/appdynamics-gradle-plugin/2.0/appdynamics-gradle-plugin-2.0.pom

https // repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/appdynamics/appdynamics-gradle-plugin/2.0/appdynamics-gradle-plugin-2.0.jar

file /c/ Users/Piyush/.m2/repository/com/appdynamics/appdynamics-gradle-plugin/2.0/appdynamics-gradle-plugin-2.0.pom

file /C /Users/Piyush/.m2/repository/com/appdynamics/appdynamics-gradle-plugin/2.0/appdynamics-gradle-plugin-2.0.jar

Required by:
        ECommerce-Android-master:app:unspecified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow this istructions:

> Clone a local copy of this project with
> git clone https://github.com/Appdynamics/ECommerce-Android
>
> Open Android Studio and Import Project (select app/build.gradle)

Android Studio will ask you to build the project with gradle.
Gradle will use the `build.gradle` inside the project.

The version of gradle is inside the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zi
```

Check for example the file inside the [app](https://github.com/Appdynamics/ECommerce-Android/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties):

Comment: sir, i made changes as instructed in gradle-wrapper.properties. it is still prompting that error. i have updated the error log please have a look. Thank you sir for your effort

Answer (score 0):

You need put a directory called "adeum-maven-repo" in your project setup .

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO39/Instrument+an+Android+Application#InstrumentanAndroidApplication-SetupforGradle